# If A is such that $(A+2I)^2=0$, prove that $A+I$ is invertible.

Tags: matrices, inverse

I'm stuck on the *second* question of this matrix exercise:

> Consider a matrix $A$ $\in$ $\mathcal{M}_n(K)$ such that $(A+2I)^2=0$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.
>
> 1. Prove that $A$ is invertible and describe the $A^{-1}$ matrix as a function of $A$.
> 2. Prove that $(A+I)$ is invertible.

Solution for 1.:

$(A+2I)^2=0$ $\Rightarrow$

$\Rightarrow A^2 + 4AI +4I^2 = 0 \Rightarrow$

$\Rightarrow A(A+4I) = -4I \Rightarrow$

$A(-\frac {A+4I}{4}) = I$, therefore A is invertible, and $A^{-1} = -\frac 14A-I.$

I've tried pretty much every replacement I could think of, but no matter what, I couldn't come to the form $(A+I)B=I$.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Expand the polynomial in powers of $A+I$ instead of powers of $A$. $(A+2I)^2=((A+I)+I)^2=(A+I)^2+2(A+I)+I=0$. Therefore $I=(A+I)(-A-3I)$

Comment: From $A^2+4A+4I=0$ you get $4(A+I)=-A^2$.  Since the right side is invertible, the left side is invertible.

Comment: The title is complete nonsense, and not at all what your question asks.

Comment: I fixed the title (and some of the formatting) for you. Titles should be informative, and supposedly reflect the question.

Comment: Darn, I had it in front of me the whole time! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}(A+2I)^2=0&\iff (A+I+I)^2=0\\&\iff(A+I)^2+2(A+I)+I=0\\&\iff(A+I)\bigl((A+I)+2I\bigr)=-I\\&\iff(A+I)\bigl(-(A+I)-2I\bigr)=I.\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

From $A^2 + 4AI +4I^2 = 0 $ one gets $-\frac 1 4A^2 = (A + I)$. Since $A$ is invertible , so is $A+I$

Answer (score 3):

$A+I$ is not invertible implies there exists $x\neq 0$ with $A(x)=-x$, this implies that $(A^2+4A+4I)(x)=x-4x+4x=x=0$ contradiction.

Comment: You just need to add, for the OP's understanding, that $(A+I)$ non invertible means that $\ker (A+I) \neq {0} \iff \exists x s.t. (A+I)x=0 $